# How to calculate the confidence interval for $d^\prime$ (d prime)?

Tags: statistics, signal-detection

I have an experiment with $N$ signal trials and $M$ no signal trials and I have measure the number of hits $nHit$ and the number of false alarms $nFA$. From this I can compute the probability of a hit $p(Hit)$, the probability of a false alarm $p(FA)$, and the index of sensitivity $d^\prime$. Specifically, I define $d^\prime=z(p(Hit))-z(p(FA))$ where $z(.)$ is the inverse of the normal distribution cumulative density function.

I can also find the confidence intervals of $p(Hit)$ and $p(FA)$ with the inverse of the binomial distribution cumulative density function. Is there a similar way of calculating the confidence interval of $d^\prime$ that doesn't involve resampling the data (e.g., bootstrapping).

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done much d-prime stuff for a long time, but perhaps check out the `discrim` function in the `sensR` package in R.

http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/sensR/docs/discrim

For example, if I understand correctly you could pass arguments like the following: a person had 60 items correct out of 100 and null hypothesis d-prime is 0 (you can specify either a null d-prime or a null probability of correct).

```
library(sensR)
discrim(correct = 60, total = 100, d.prime0=0)
```

This produces the  following output:

```
Estimates for the duotrio discrimination protocol with 60 correct
answers in 100 trials. One-sided p-value and 95 % two-sided confidence
intervals are based on the 'exact' binomial test. 

        Estimate Std. Error Lower  Upper
pc         0.600    0.04899   0.5 0.6967
pd         0.200    0.09798   0.0 0.3934
d-prime    1.115    0.31360   0.0 1.6958

Result of difference test:
'exact' binomial test:  p-value = 0.02844 
Alternative hypothesis: d-prime is greater than 0
```

I.e., you appear to get a lower and upper confidence interval on d-prime (e.g., 0 to 1.6958). The confidence interval can be specified with the `conf.level` argument but defaults to 0.95. There's more details in Christensen (2015).

Christensen, R. H. B. (2015). Statistical methodology for sensory discrimination tests and its implementation in sensR. http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.192.6348&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: The sensR library only considers paradigms where d' can be calculated directly from Pc (e.g., 2AFC). This is a much easier proble, since there is only one random variable. In the more general case where d' depends on pit and pFA, the library and it's approaches are hopeless.

Comment: Okay. Makes sense. I'll leave the answer up in case it helps others searching for the simpler problem.